Do angels have different dwelling places?
Mark 12:25 is presented in slightly different manner in different versions. For instance:
Weymouth New Testament:

For when they have risen from among the dead, men do not marry and women are not given in marriage, but they are as angels are in Heaven.

World English Bible:

For when they will rise from the dead, they neither marry nor are given in marriage, but are like angels in heaven.

The WNT stands apart for the reason that Jesus says that the risen people are as angels ARE in heaven. Now, there are also angels who are on the earth , like the Guardian Angels. Are they permitted to live like human beings albeit in an invisible form ? There is a hypothesis that the 'Sons of God' as referred to in Genesis  6:1-2 are those angels who descended on the earth and mingled with human beings, entering into marriage. If that be true, are there different categories of angels :those  that stay in heaven as batchelors and spinsters Vs those that dwell on the earth and have progeny ? Are there any apocryphal writings or traditional beliefs on the subject

given this might not have been mainstream - are there any boundaries on whose beliefs are of interest? Virtually any belief we can think of had some Christian faith group somewhere that would have liked it - for this one there's often felt to be some tension in Hebrews to do with people over-venerating or worshipping angels. A group like that might have believed there were angels on earth, or lots of things, but we don't have their side of the story and it becomes conjecture. For you where are the boundaries of the enquiry?

@Kadalikatt Joseph Sibichan We are at risk of going to mythology if we start thinking that bodiless angels adopt bodies in order to get access to sexual pleasures with bodily girls and women. Sorry, but it is impossible, for angels are immersed in such a contemplative pleasures of glorifying the invisible, eternal God that the highest possible romantic pleasure and infatuation praised by best of writers and poets, be it Romeo's with Juliet or of Tristan with Isolda, or Kais with Leila will seem to them as a dung and manure, to say the least.

As is indicated by the passage provided by the OP (Mark 12:25), the angels in Genesis 6 were not "permitted" to mingle with mankind in the sense that God sanctioned it. There are several clues to this fact:
In Genesis 6:2, the sons of God take women of their choice and marry them.
God's response in 6:3 is to declare that He will no longer contend with humans anymore. He then puts the earth on a one hundred twenty day countdown until the flood spawns re-creation.
In Genesis 6:4, we learn that the Nephalim (Giants) are the outcome of these unions between spiritual beings and the daughters of men. There is some indication that this continues after the flood as in the books to follow, the Israelites spend considerable times contending with and wiping out the Nephalim (Numbers 13:33, Deuteronomy 2:20-21, 3:1-11 Rephaites, Joshua 11:21-22 Sons of Anak, 14:12-15 Sons of Anak, 1 Samuel 17:49-51 Goliath, 2 Samuel 21:15-22, etc.).
As is common in biblical narrative, we see the action (marriage between heavenly and earthy beings) and then the consequence (flood, centuries of difficult battles against the nephalim).
In fact, the first time Israel is not able to enter the promised land is because the spies that were sent into the land saw people who "were like nephalim (giants)" in the land and they were afraid to enter:
Numbers 13:31-33 (NRSV):


Then the men who had gone up with him said, “We are not able to go up against this people, for they are stronger than we are.”

So they brought to the Israelites an unfavorable report of the land that they had spied out, saying, “The land that we have gone
through as spies is a land that devours its inhabitants, and all the
people that we saw in it are of great size.”

There we saw the Nephilim (the Anakites come from the Nephilim); and to ourselves we seemed like grasshoppers, and so we seemed to
them.”



So to answer the OPs question, there aren't classes of angels, some who stay in heaven as bachelors and some who are permitted on earth to marry. The negative consequences are a biblical way of indicating these were improper acts on the part of the angels.
In the same way, many would further argue that the position of this narrative, following the fall of man in Gen 3, suggests a parallel rebellion of many spiritual beings such as the satan. As much as the flood that follows is an act of destruction, it also serves as an act of re-creation beginning again with Noah as a new Adam.

This answer really needs more information to indicate which groups of people historically held this view in light of OP’s question. As I read it it’s not looking for personal opinion but rather historical viewpoints.

@bob This view is/was held by many including early church writers. Historically speaking Philip of Alexandria “On the Giants and On the Unchangeableness of God.” Justin Martyr “Second Apology”, Athenagoras “A Plea For Christians, Tertullian ”On the Veiling of Virgins”, Irenaeus “Against Heresies”, and Lactantius “The Divine Institutes”. Also several second temple Jewish works, modern commentaries. Hope that helps. Maybe you can help me with the downvote on this

I think if you put what you have in your comment near the top of and all throughout your answer, it will strengthen it greatly and increase the number of votes it gets b/c it will go from your own interpretation of Scripture, which people will disagree with if it differs from their own, to a presentation of a historical viewpoint by a group of people which is a statement of fact (“they believed this”) which people can acknowledge even if they don’t hold that belief.

@bob thanks Bob for the tip. I’ll do that

This is a dialect mismatch between the WNT translation and the OP.
"They are as angels in Heaven" doesn't mean "They are in Heaven as angels." That is a subtlety of word order on WNT's part, which they haven't anticipated will carry over wrongly into the OP's English. This is a perennial problem with us having a few major translations when we need thousands of dialect translations.
ἀλλ’ εἰσὶν ὡς ἄγγελοι ἐν τοῖς οὐρανοῖς
Underneath this is a problem of translating Greek into English. Our language relies on strong converses. So if you say you are in Heaven you are producing what Derrida calls a différance from the unspoken converse that you are not on Earth. (Wikipedia amusingly spell différance wrong - it's not allowed to have a capital! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff%C3%A9rance)
If an Ancient Greek-speaker says "ἀλλ’ εἰσὶν ὡς ἄγγελοι ἐν τοῖς οὐρανοῖς" and we ask them "wait, do you mean they are in heaven as angels or that they are as angels in heaven" they'd be puzzled and eventually reply "yes!"
Because the particle ὡς has put the whole idea into a comparative sense (or even a mood). This is not a clause that is telling us where angels are or what they are doing, it is a sub-clause that is comparing how they are and do... to its main clause.
I believe that probably makes the passage useless for the OP's project of research into what beliefs there were about angels. And that's a shame as it looked quite interesting. I'll update this if I can find any good passages - angels are categorized aren't they but we usually think of it as being by their official ranks more than whether they have children with humans. But at least the language point can be covered off concisely.

Thanks FelixLXX for the scholarly inputs . See Lk 22:43 and Gal 1:8 which speak of ' angel from heaven'  .

And Mark 1:13 simply says: "  he was in the wilderness forty days, being tempted[g] by Satan. He was with the wild animals, and angels attended him. "  Here, Mark does not specify that the angels came from heaven. On the other hand, Jesus during his trial,  speaks of  the Father who is ever- ready to send angels 'from heaven ' to protect him.

@KadalikattJosephSibichan but if someone's metaphysics is that principles in Heaven become substantials on Earth, they might need to introduce a vector between the two. And they might then personify it (e.g. as Hermes). This is too often called Platonism but it's found widely, anciently and in popular usage. In a framework like that angels are necessarily from heaven, and it's the opposite that needs explaining to those people. otoh, a whole opposite type of framework, where people believe in divine beings dwelling on earth, would be harder to find in the history-of-ideas.

So Hermes is evidence that ancient people were familiar with the idea of the Father sending a winged person as a "messenger" from heaven. For races of demigods, all that springs to mind is things like cyclopes and amazons, which most people placed firmly in the domain of the mythical/allegorical.

Jesus told his disciples that they’d see am the angels ascending and descending on the Son of Man (him), so just b/c it doesn’t state where referenced angels come from doesn’t mean they didn’t come down from heaven to minister to Jesus.
